# calling model in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I having difficulty in calling the method. I have two two button on the same form. One button is saving all the detail in a text file. Another button is validating date of birth fields. The validate button is not functioning. Any help.
Below is the code I have tried:

controller:

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Sample/

    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(Information information, string buttonType)
    {
        if (buttonType=="Register")
        {
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(information.Surname + Environment.NewLine + information.DOBP + Environment.NewLine + information.Email + Environment.NewLine + information.Gender + Environment.NewLine + information.Tel);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            return File(stream, "text/plain", "Registration.txt");

        }
        if (buttonType=="Validate")
        {

        }
        return View(information);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }  
}
```

Here is my class called DOBvalidator:

```
public class DOBvalidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    public DOBvalidator (int minimumAge)
    {               
         MinimumAge = minimumAge;
         ErrorMessage = "You are under 18";                
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime date;
        if ((value!=null && DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(),out date)))
        {
            return date.AddYears(MinimumAge) < DateTime.Now;
        }              

        return false;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name, MinimumAge);
    }

    public int MinimumAge { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
<p align="center">
     <input type="submit" value="Register" name="buttonType" />                   
     <input type="button" value="Validate" name="buttonType"/>
</p>
```

Comment: where you are using you attribute? what is happening inside buttonType==“Validate”?

Answer (score 1):

This seems an unusual way of doing things to me.  I would have thought the standard way to do this would be to just have a register button and make that validate and then save if the data is valid.

But ignoring that here is what you need to do.  Both buttons need to submit to the server.  So in your view change the code for the validate button to

```
<input type="submit" value="Validate" name="buttonType" />
```

Then in the HttpPost Create method in your controller

change

```
 if (buttonType=="Validate")
 {

 }
```

to

```
if (buttonType == "Validate")
{
    var validator = new DOBvalidator(18);
    var isValid = validator.IsValid(information.DOBP);
    if(!isValid)
    {
         ModelState.AddModelError("DOBP", validator.ErrorMessage);
    }              
}
```

I set it to 18 because the error message mentions 18.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably try:

```
<input type="button" value="Validate" name="buttonType" id="btnValidate" runAt="server" onclick="ValidateButton_Click" />
```

On Server side:

```
protected void ValidateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    DOBvalidator.Validate();

    if (DOBvalidator.IsValid)
    {
      // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: if (buttonType=="Validate")
            {
                
            }
            return View(information);

Comment: what to insert?

Comment: I think you are suggesting this for webforms.

Comment: In mvc the attribute runat server will not be called and neither the method